# Deploy from Sandbox to Production Org SFDX

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli

I created an SFDX project with manifest in VSCODE, authorized my sandbox org and retrieved source from manifest on the default package.xml. At this point I had the base setup with classes, triggers, aura etc.. I only made a change to a class file, right click deploy source to org which deploys to my sandbox. Now I want to deploy to my production org, but I get the following error sf:INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations

How can I deploy this file to production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## As of Now

You can use `sfdx force:source:deploy -l RunLocalTests ...` to run tests. This will enable deploying source-formatted metadata directly to production.

---

*Original Answer*

## As of Spring '19

`force:source:deploy` doesn't support deploying to production, as it always specifies to run no tests, and tests are required for deployment to production. You can either use unlocked packages `force:package:install`, or you can use `force:source:convert` followed by `force:mdapi:deploy` to deploy to production.

---

Note to future visitors: This feature may have been added after this answer was written. Be sure to [check the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm).

Comment: if I understand correctly, by using force:source:convert I will be zipping my current project and then deploying it, is that correct? When I originally did my retrieve source from manifest on the package.xml it pulled in classes, trigger etc.., I have only made a change to 1 specific class file. Is there a way to only package that specific file. I don't need to deploy everything.

Comment: @MarkC5000 You'd have to copy the class to a new deploy folder, include the metadata file and package.xml, and deploy it. It'd be a lot easier at this point to just use a Change Set at this point.

Comment: as of 10/19 source deploy has been updated to enable running tests.
-l RunLocalTests is the option.

Comment: @ebt I knew about that, just forgot about this question. Thanks for reminding me, I'll update it.